# Force users pass by firewall for a network with 2 gateways, one over firewall and other direct connection

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, gateway

I have a network with 2 default gateways (i.e. A, B). A is behind a firewall, while B is directly connected.

I set DHCP for all domain computers to have Default Gateway for A. The firewall is a proxy server (Microsoft TMG). If users doesn't set the proxy (A) in Internet Options, connection is automatically redirected to gateway B and simply access the internet.

How can I prevent this from happening in which users who did not input the proxy should not access the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If your default gateway it set via DHCP to gateway A (your TMG proxy) then all client pcs sending to addresses outside of their respective subnet/vlan must be sent to that gateway A, irregardless of if a proxy has been configured in IE or not. However, unless there is a layer 3 switch or router in between your client PCs and the TMG proxy server, it cannot be a a valid gateway.

The gateway B you have configured that's directly connected, is that a L3 switch, router or just a plain old L2 switch?

Also, I'd check to see what routes you have entered into your directly connected gateway B (if it is a L3 device) because that may be causes issues as well.

Comment: The other gateway is a hardware firewall with intrusion detection system but is not yet fully configured to simulate or work as a replacement for TMG (D-Link) and needs to much procedures.

Comment: What private IPs are configured for your gateways and what subnet(s) for your clients? You really only need to list one or two client subnets.

Comment: 10.0.0.2 for Hardware firewall and 10.0.0.3 for TMG (both gateway and proxy). Subnet 10.255.255.X and Subnet mask: 255.0.0.0